# Reading and writing dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, calloc

I have some code with following parts:

```
typedef unsigned long long int ulli_t;
typedef unsigned int obj_t;
// --- SOME UNIMPORTANT PART OF CODE
objects = (obj_t*)malloc(hw*sizeof(obj_t));
objNums = (ulli_t*)calloc(hw, sizeof(ulli_t));
printf("%#x, %#x\n", objects, objNums);
// --- SOME UNIMPORTANT CODE
/// NEXT PART IS for-CYCLED
objNums[k] ++;
if (k>=Nobj) {
   objects[k] = obj;
   Nobj++;
   printf(" %lu - %#x - %#x\n", k, objects+k, objNums+k);
};
```

And I've got an output of this part of code:

```
0xaafdf9d8, 0xaad693b0
 0 - 0 - 0xaafdf9d8
 1 - 0 - 0xaafdf9dc
 2 - 0 - 0xaafdf9e0
 3 - 0 - 0xaafdf9e4
 4 - 0 - 0xaafdf9e8
 5 - 0 - 0xaafdf9ec
 6 - 0 - 0xaafdf9f0
 7 - 0 - 0xaafdf9f4
 8 - 0 - 0xaafdf9f8
 9 - 0 - 0xaafdf9fc
 10 - 0 - 0xaafdfa00
 11 - 0 - 0xaafdfa04
```

So, here is the question - If 'objects' variable is non-zero then why does 'objects+k' is zero?
When I make :

```
printf(" %lu - %#x - %#x\n", k, objects[k], objNums[k]);
```

I get lines like:

```
value of k - 0 - hex value of objNums[k]
```

Why is that?
I already got my brain broken thinking about that thing.

Comment: You do `objects[k] = obj;` - are you sure `obj` isn't zero at that point?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure that obj is not a zero at the time. I thought of that. I printed it out just a moment ago. And it was not a zero at all.
But there is some other thing.
You see, when k=0, the objNums+k is equal to previously printed 'objects' pointer value and not to the 'objNums' value. That make me very confusing.

Comment: Probably some important part of code is missing.

Comment: objects[k] should be getting assigned to whatever obj is.  Without seeing more of the code it's hard to tell.

Comment: `objects` is declared as `obj_t* objects;`
`obj` is declared as `obj_t obj;`

Comment: @SergyKanaev That's obvious what objects is declared as.  What is obj?

Comment: @SergyKanaev What is obj_t?  Obvious it's a typedef, but of what primitive type?

Comment: @dbrank0 here is more code. Nothing is cut exceptfor its completion http://pastebin.com/2CrQRPsu
@annoying_squid `typedef unsigned int obj_t;`

Comment: How are you assigning obj?  Is obj supposed to be zero?

Comment: Are you sure your k is long unsigned?

Comment: `obj` can be zero but only once. This code counts different colors in picture and writes it to `objects` and its count to `objNums`. The different colors count is `Nobj`.
I've pestebined more adequate quoto from the code to [link]http://pastebin.com/2CrQRPsu

Comment: @dbdrank0 `k` is `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: after setting `k` to `unsigned long int` the code worked as it was supposed to. Thus I can make a conclusion, that the problem was about type-casting, wasn'it?

Comment: No. First two specifiers in your printf printed halfs of your long long. One part was always 0.

Comment: Oh, I see. it. It is because of stack-passed arguments of function. Thanks.

Comment: Third column was actually objects+k. Compare pointers and you will see. Objnums+k was never printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using %lu to print your long long. You should use %llu.